# PMA error : mbstring is missing

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin, apache2.2, mbstring

I am running on Windows 7 64 bit with:

- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.2.8
- MySQL 5.1 (essentials)

installed and **configured manually**. As you all know, for this since MySQL essentials has no GUI for interaction the best suit is PhpMyAdmin. I am trying to get **phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-english**, downloaded from the PMA website, into my Apache web server.

After all configuration work, now I get an error message when I try to log into PMA saying:

> "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP
>   configuration."

In this forum it was mentioned that possible causes for this are the unavailability of `php_mbstring.dll` in php folder or else the `extension_dir` variable in `php.ini` is set to `./` which is the current folder.

I checked in the `ext` folder and the `.dll` file is available and the `extension_dir` variable is set to `./ext`. And I tried setting the variable to `C:/php/ext` which is the absolute location, still it doesn't work. Any help on this concern would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the mbstring extension is just not activated in php.ini. Look for the line

```
;extension mbstring = php_mbstring.dll
```

and remove the leading ;

Also make sure that you are looking at the correct php.ini since there could be more than one in your installation.

Comment: That is also done. Yet no good! Thank you @Lorenz... :) Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you check the correct php.ini file ? In WAMP it's the one in the folder apache/bin.

Comment: Yeap.. What I have checked is what is in the 'C:/php' directory.

Comment: Look at the error log. Is there an error about loading the dll ?

Comment: This is what the apache log says:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_pdo_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Did you restart your apache?